# Check if values in an array exist in another array using sql

Tags: sql, arrays, hana

I want to perform some operations based on, if we have some values in one array existing in another array. Following is part of my code where I am trying to handle the arrays. I have 2 arrays CL_NM[ ] and CL_NM_FIN[ ]. I would want to perform an update if a value in CL_NM[ ] doesn't exist in CL_NM_FIN[ ]. Please help me on how should I modify my code.
[image: Here is my code]

Upon trying to do this, I am getting that the column already exists error because the for loop is not going through all elements in CL_NM_FIN[ ] before going into the else condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using the following:

```
    DO 
BEGIN
    DECLARE arr1 TINYINT ARRAY = ARRAY(1,2,3,4);
    DECLARE arr2 INTEGER ARRAY = ARRAY(1,2);


--convert array in table rst1 with column name col1
    rst1 = UNNEST(:arr1) as (COL1);
--convert array in table rst2 with column name col1 
    rst2 = UNNEST(:arr2) as (COL1);
--query with minus
    select  col1 from :rst1  
              minus
    select col1 from :rst2;
END;
```